# In Python3, how to create a priority queue based on the second element of its sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a list with sublists:

```
a = [[1,83],[2,7],[3,10]]
```

I want to create a priority queue based on the second element of a's sublist,which means if I use

```
a.pop()
```

The output will be

```
[2,7]
```

since it has the smallest second element.

Comment: Just create a max heap with the node value equal to the second element of each array

Comment: Are you asking how to do this with [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html), Python's priority queue, or do you want some other implementation? And what code have you tried so far?

Comment: See the [priority queue implementation notes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) in Python's [**`heapq`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing built-in list:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     def pop(self, index=None):
...         if index is None:
...             try:
...                 index = min(enumerate(self), key=lambda x: x[1][1])[0]
...             except ValueError:
...                 # allow for empty lists
...                 pass
...         args = () if index is None else (index,)
...         return super(MyList, self).pop(*args)
...         
...         
>>> L = MyList([[1,83],[2,7],[3,10]])
>>> L.pop()
[2, 7]
>>> L
[[1, 83], [3, 10]]
```

Hack way that works on directly on built-in list instead of custom class:

```
>>> import gc
>>> 
>>> def mypop(list_, index=None):
...     if index is None:
...         try:
...             index = min(enumerate(list_), key=lambda x: x[1][1])[0]
...         except ValueError:
...             # allow for empty lists
...             pass
...     args = () if index is None else (index,)
...     return list_.pop(*args)
... 
>>> gc.get_referents(list.__dict__)[0]["mypop"] = mypop
>>> 
>>> L = [[1,83],[2,7],[3,10]]
>>> L.mypop()
[2, 7]
>>> L.mypop()
[3, 10]
>>> L.mypop()
[1, 83]
>>> L.mypop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in mypop
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

^ Hey, **don't use this**, I only post it here for fun!

Comment: Oh that second one is a nasty trick.  Do you know if there's any reasoning behind it returning a `dict` or is it an omission?

Comment: Hi.  Built-in types use a mappingproxy for their `__dict__`, but if you know some python implementation detail there are tricks to get at the real dict.  See [issue1303614](http://bugs.python.org/issue1303614) for inspiration.  I once again stress that this is black magic and should never be used in serious code...

Comment: The first one works very well, but is there any way to make it faster? I guess it will run in O(n^2) .

Comment: I think it should be O(n), why do you think O(n^2) ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've done this, I've found it useful to pull out the value I want to sort by into the first element of a tuple, to use in the priority queue. It's especially useful when you have a list of data and you want to push some of it through a fitness function to get a sorted list as you're building it (ordered by heap property).

The other answers are basically telling you to sort the list. However, if you are generating the lists as you go, it can be helpful to keep the list in priority order as inserting is average case O(1). If you are running a real-time application (e.g. game), and need to return the best-found result within a certain time, you can run your simulation, store the results, and when you hit your timeout, the first element of the queue will be the lowest priority with no additional sorting.

```
import heapq
a = [[1,83],[2,7],[3,10]]
my_queue = []
for item in a:
  # assume that in this case, the item is calculated rather than just pulled from list a
  heapq.heappush(my_queue,(a[1],a))
```

The `my_queue` object now contains a tuple of the sorting value and the original list ordered by heap property. You can pop them off in order:

```
while my_queue:
  heapq.heappop(my_queue)
```

Result:

```
>> (7, [2, 7])
>> (10, [3, 10])
>> (83, [1, 83])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [[1,83],[2,7],[3,10]]
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> a.pop()
[2,7]
```

This sorts your list in reverse order based on the second value in each sublist. Then `pop`ing off the end of this sorted list gives you your expected output.